# can't get my mastermind game to work (one error )

Tags: python

Something is going wrong at the line:

```py
copy_guess[:], copy_code[:] = zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(guess,code) if a != b))
```

error massage is:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

```
import random
max_range = 5
code_lines = 4
def generate_code():
    code_arr = []
    for i in range(code_lines):
        code_arr.append(random.randint(0,max_range))
    return code_arr
def right_position(guess,code):
    right_positions = 0
    answer_position = [len(set(i)) == 1 for i in zip(guess,code)]
    for x in answer_position:
        if x == True:
            right_positions += 1
    return right_positions
def all_positions_right(guess,code):
    answer_position = [len(set(i)) == 1 for i in zip(guess,code)]
    return answer_position
```

this is where the problem is i think. it worked quite good without this but not evry time.

```
def wrong_position(guess,code):
    char_number = 0
    copy_guess = guess
    copy_code = code
    copy_guess[:], copy_code[:] = zip(*((a, b) for a, b in zip(copy_guess,copy_code) if a != b))
    for a in copy_guess:
        for b in copy_code:
            if a == b:
               char_number += 1   
    return char_number
```

the code is split in two files.

```
from mastermind_funcs import generate_code, right_position, wrong_position , all_positions_right

code_lines = 4
def guesslist_func():
    i = 1
    guess_list = []
    while i <= code_lines:
        x = int(input("guess number "))
        guess_list.append(x)
        i += 1
    return guess_list
def main():
    right_code = generate_code()
    print(right_code)
    true_list = [True,True,True,True]
    value = True
    guess_count = 0
    while value:
        guess_list = guesslist_func()
        if all_positions_right(guess_list,right_code) == true_list:
            value = False
            print("grattis, coden var " , right_code , ".")
        else:
            if right_position(guess_list,right_code) > 0:
                print(right_position(guess_list,right_code))
                print(wrong_position(guess_list,right_code))
            else:
                print(wrong_position(guess_list,right_code))
        guess_count += 1
    print("du klarade det på" , guess_count , "gissningar.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

evrything works fine except wrong_position

Comment: We're going to need some sample data (`guess_list` and `right_code` at least) in order to help. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your `wrong_position` ode works fine for me, if I pass it two arrays of 4.  What you passing it?  Have you printed `guess` and `code` to know what you're getting?  If either of those lists are empty, then I get that error.

Comment: You don't have to initialize `copy_guess`, `copy_code`, or `guess_list`.  Just do `copy_guess, copy_code = zip(...)`.

Comment: What is the code of `all_positions_right`? The error suggest that guess_list and right_code hold the same numbers

Comment: code is a randomly generated list of 0-5 and guess is your guess,  all_position_right is just a def to see if both lists are the same and end the loop

Comment: I understand what you think it (all_position_right) does, but I guess it doesn't work as you expect, because the error would happen when guess numbes at all positions are correct

Comment: "Something is going wrong at the line:" Okay, so **did you try to check** what the result of the `zip` is (for example, by creating and displaying a `list` of the values)? Did you try to check the value of `guess` and of `code` when the problem occurs? (Incidentally, do you know that `copy_guess = guess` **does not** copy anything?) Please read [ask] and [mre] and keep in mind that this is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is that inside `wrong_position` function you mutate `guess` and `code` and thus also `guess_list` and `right_code`. You can print the 2 lists after you call `wrong_position` function to see for your self and debug.

Here is [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate what is going on

```
def eggs(foo):
    bar = foo
    bar[::] = [4, 5, 6]
    print(f'foo: {foo}')
    print(f'bar: {bar}')

spam = [1, 2, 3]
eggs(spam)
print(f'spam: {spam}')
```

output

```
foo: [4, 5, 6]
bar: [4, 5, 6]
spam: [4, 5, 6]
```

So, to fix the error, change

```
copy_guess = guess
copy_code = code
```

to

```
copy_guess = guess[::]
copy_code = code[::]
```

Further reading [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/4046632)

That said, there are a lot things in this code that can and should be done differently to be more pythonic.

Comment: If that's the problem, then this is a duplicate of the linked question and should be closed (as a duplicate) and deleted (as not a useful signpost, and for showing a complete lack of debugging effort).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I have already voted to close it for lack of debug details before they added the full code. If I retract, I cannot vote again. Decided just to help instead and it is too long for comment. I don't mind if it is closed and/or to delete my answer